# Cannot make Conan + CMake + QT work together. No valid Qt version found for target

Tags: qt, cmake, conan

When I set `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` cmake says

> CMake Warning (dev) in src/ProjQt/CMakeLists.txt:   AUTOGEN: No
> valid Qt version found for target ProjQt.  AUTOMOC   disabled.
> Consider adding:
>
> ```
> find_package(Qt<QTVERSION> COMPONENTS Core)
> ```
>
> to your CMakeLists.txt file.

If I add `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core)` before `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)`

> CMake Warning at src/ProjQt/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
> By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
> asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5",
> but   CMake did not find one.
> ...

I thought conan provides a custom `find_package` which behaviour is conan-related first, then default if failed but it looks like it doesn't provide it like vcpkg does

All these actions are done after `include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue again and this is how I managed to fix it:

1. Set an appropriate conan generator to generate needed config CMake files

- I use `generators = "cmake_find_package_multi"` as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/6251#issuecomment-877303859) (Again my own issue)

2. Conan now generates a whole lot of `<PKG>Config/Target.cmake` files (in my case), we need to point CMake to look for configurations in that folder as specified in [conan docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package_multi.html#cmake-find-package-multi-generator-reference) and here [in CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html)
3. At that point `AUTOMOC`, `AUTOUIC` and `AUTORCC` should work with this piece of config:

```
find_package(Qt5 CONFIG REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
```

---

I've encountered two types of different issues later on …

---

```
AutoMoc error
-------------
"SRC:/src/<thisfilename>.cpp"
contains a "Q_OBJECT" macro, but does not include "<thisfilename>.moc"!
Consider to
  - add #include "<thisfilename>.moc"
  - enable SKIP_AUTOMOC for this file
```

This is resolved either by moving `Q_OBJECT` class into header or adding `#include <thisfilename.moc>` below the class, CMake automatically populates direct path to this file without paths nesting. For example if I have a file called "test.cpp" I have to do this:

```
#include <QObject>

class TestObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
};

#include <test.moc>
```

---

Linker errors with unresolved references to `metaObject`, `qt_metacast`, `qt_metacall`, etc …
In that case it means that moc's generated source code was not added into compilation.
It can be resolved either with adding header files along with `.cpp` files in `add_executable` call:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
    include/*.h
    src/*.cpp
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

the above has an obvious downside, after each newly created header you have to reconfigure CMake to generate moc stuff

The other way to fix it is to include a file `#include <moc_thisfilename.cpp>` in the `Q_OBJECT`'s cpp implementation file like that:
`test.hpp`

```
#include <QObject>

class TestObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
};
```

`test.cpp`

```
#include <test.hpp>
#include <moc_test.cpp>
```

---

I haven't yet find a way to forget about this moc generation magic and make CMake autoinclude everything in a smart way when including header containing `Q_OBJECT` related stuff